# Website access protect by password

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to create a password protected website. Here I want to do if a user first time visit to my website then need to insert password to access my website. First time they entered the password they can freely access my website.

This is how I do it using `javascript` and `php`:

```
<?php if($page == 'index'): ?>
    <script language="Javascript">
            //prompt.
            var password;
            var correctPass = "123456"; 
            password = prompt("Enter in the password:","");

            if(password == correctPass) {
                    alert('click OK to view this site');
            } else {
                    window.location = "http://google.com"
            } 
            //->
    </script>               
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is working but my problem is if user go to the index page again they need to insert the password.

can anybody tell me how I fix this issue. 
Thank you.

Comment: you need to save IP address of user in database and check everytime when request will come from same IP. If same then allow else validate.

Comment: for anonymous user, consider storing information in cookie because you have no way remembering which user has entered password but it will be browser dependent then!

Comment: @DeepKakkar, Can I do this without using a database? thank you

Comment: Take a look at Sessions.

Comment: Hmmm, are you really storing the correct password in javascript ? If so, anyone can see it with firebug and then enter freely...

Comment: You should read a good book about security on web applications, because your starting point suggests that you don't have really good idea of how things are supposed to work... imho.

Comment: @user3733831 _without database_ then why do you need php. Html5 localstorage/webstorage/sessionstorage, cookies will help you.

Comment: I just needed to this for temporary usage. Thats why I did it like this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not do this in JavaScript. Anyone can look at your source code and see the password. Do the password check in PHP instead. Then use `$_SESSION` variables to save the state while they are on your site. You may also want to use `$_COOKIE` variables for long term access, but just `$_SESSION` by itself is generally preferred in most cases for password access.

An alternate way to do it is with your web server. For example, if you are using Apache you can create a `.htaccess` file at the root of your website to ask for a name and password. That way you don't even need to code anything.

To do the second option, create a file called .htaccess in the root of your web directory. In the file put this in:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /opt/passwords/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

(where /opt/passwords is a directory location outside of your web directory. It can be anywhere you want, you just want to make sure it is not anywhere within your web directory (otherwise it will be available for public viewing)).

In that directory, create a file called .htpasswd. This file will simply take a username and encrypted password. This page will allow you to create your name with password encryption: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/ .  Just paste that into your .htpasswd file.

With that said, any password you use can be intercepted if you are only using http and not https, but setting up https is a bit difficult if you haven't done it before.

Comment: Which of those options would you prefer? (I added an alternative to my answer).

Comment: these name for folder of /opt/passwords is necessary?

Comment: my project url in localhost is like this - localhost/web/myComputer/

Comment: No, but they do have to be an absolute path. So you need to know where you are going to put your .htpasswd file and create the absolute path to that file. Despite what I said above, in theory, you can put it in your in your web directory and it should be hidden from public view. So, if you need to do this, it should be okay, but you will need the full path to your web directory.

Comment: `.htaccess` file in myComputer directory and `.htpasswd` file in web folder. So how would be the path for password file?

Comment: Is this Apache or IIS you are running as your web server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80140/discussion-between-user3733831-and-kojow7).

Answer (score 1):

This is not safe. User can have disabled JS.

One of correct ways is to use [http auth](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html).

Answer (score 0):

first of all are you putting the plain password in java script itself???
never do that and also

if($page == 'index')

always constructs to true so the logic wont work use cookies or session

Comment: You should explain why, "never do that", or the person asking questions like these will never actually learn anything.